# Google apps script target text between two tags

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script to do something relatively straight forward with Google app script (google documents scripts - i think they are a version of javascript if that helps):

I want to search from the tag: {start} up to the tag {end} and then make any pre-defined keywords bold. Then, once completed I want to delete the tags {start} and {end}.

For the following:

```
{start}this, is, some text, in here{end}
this is, some text, in here
```

I wrote (mish-mashed) this code together, it searches paragraphs for words and makes them bold if they are found - that works, however my main issue is that it will also then replace words outside of the block (start->end) with bold when found; I do not want the script to affect other blocks or paragraphs in the document(s).

```
function emboldenText(docID, textToHighlight) {

  var doc  = DocumentApp.openById(docID);

  var paras = doc.getParagraphs();
  var textLocation = {};
  var i;
  var startLocation;

  for (i=0; i<paras.length; ++i) {    


    textLocation = paras[i].findText(textToHighlight);
    if (textLocation != null && textLocation.getStartOffset() != -1) {

      Logger.log("hit, making text bold at: "+ textLocation.getStartOffset());

      /* Make it bold! */
      textLocation.getElement().setBold(textLocation.getStartOffset(),textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive(), true);

    }
  }
}
```

I simply call that function for each word I'd like highlighted (emboldened):
i.e:

```
emboldenText(fileId,'Mustard');
    emboldenText(fileId,'Egg');
    emboldenText(fileId,'Wheat');
```

My thoughts on where to go from here are: Search the document for the word {start} and then some how grab it's element position, also grab the end position and then only replace the word with bold if it's in that section - how to actually achieve that is evading me at the moment.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function BoldBetweenTags() {
  var startTag = '{start}';
  var endTag = '{end}'
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var para = body.getParagraphs();
  for(var i in para){  
    var from = para[i].findText(startTag);
    var to =  para[i].findText(endTag,from);
    if((to != null && from != null) && ((to.getStartOffset()-1) - (from.getStartOffset()+startTag.length) > 0) ){
      para[i].editAsText().setBold(from.getStartOffset()+startTag.length, to.getStartOffset()-1, true);
    }
  }
}
```